# upload image on server with ajax for opening a preview in other page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a PHP page in which a user can insert data (with input text or files) in a DB. These data will be visualized on a web site.
I need a preview button. When the user click on preview button, it will be opened a popup window with the text and the image that he has inserted.

So, I need to upload the image on server (to get the complete path of the image and display it) without a submit button and without a refresh of the page in which the user is inserting data (because they don't have to be lost).

I was thinking of ajax and php

my code index.php:

```
<form action="filePHPForPublishing" method="Post">
    //other code...
    
    <input type="file" name="img" id="img" />
    <input type="button" id="Preview" name="Preview" value="Preview">
    
    //other code...

    <input type="submit" id="publish" name="publish" value="publish">
</form>
```

my code ajax.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#Preview").click(function() {
        var datiForm = new FormData();
        datiForm.append('image', $('#img')[0].files[0]);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: 'post',
                        url: 'ajax.php',
                        data: datiForm,
                        dataType: 'text',
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert(data);
                            return false;
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(xhr.status + ': ' + errorThrown);
                            alert("error");
                        }
                    })
    });
   
});
```

my code ajax.php:

```
$target_dir = "";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img"]["tmp_name"], $target_file);
$linkIMG =  basename( $_FILES["img"]["name"]);
```

But when I click the preview button, there is an error on the php file "undefinable variable img" in this point "`$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img"]["name"]);`"

am I doing something wrong? I'm new with ajax

Comment: in JS you are appending "image", and in PHP you are looking for "img"

Comment: Did you try with `image` instead `img`?

Comment: it doesn't work even with "image". In JS i'm appending '#img'. i think that the error is in ajax.php, because it doesn't recognize the file input. How ajax.php and index.php have to be connected?

Comment: Try this for the preview: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded?rq=1

Comment: this is for the preview in the same page. i need to open preview (with image) in other window